# How to convert flat object into intendent object by using java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have flat object 
POJO:

```
class FamilyInformation {
  String house;
  String familyMember;
}
```

with data like this:

```
[{
 house: "houseName1",
familyMember: "Son"
},
{
 house: "houseName1",
familyMember: "Mom"
},
{
 house: "houseName1",
familyMember: "Dad"
}]
```

And I want to convert it into hierarchical object
POJO:

```
class House {
  String houseName;
  List<FamilyMember> familyMembers;
}
class FamilyMember {
  String familyMember;
}
```

Every information I found is to convert it to a Map. But I want to have `List<House>` which contains `List<FamilyMember>` any ideas what should I do?

Comment: ....and what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
Map<String,List<FamilyMember>> map = list
              .stream()
              .collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(
                      FamilyInformation::getHouseName, 
                      Collectors.mapping(
                          family -> new FamilyMember(family.getFamilyMember()),
                          Collectors.toList()
                      )
                   )
               );
```

and then

```
 List<House> result = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e -> new House(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It creates me `List<FamilyMember> members = new ArrayList<>();` every iteration is that good?

Comment: Ok I tried your solution but hmm I think there is a way to do it everything in one stream. But in the other hand it won't be readable

Comment: Yes, like this `list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FamilyInformation::getHouseName,
                        Collectors.mapping(family -> new FamilyMember(family.getFamilyMember()), Collectors.toList())))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new House(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @HadiJ that's two streams still, just one line maybe if that's what you meant. Anyway (+1) since my solution was almost the same as you suggested, once you're above the 10k reps(sooner I would say), you could confirm what I am pointing to. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-stream version:

first, group by the `house` and map to a `FamilyMember` via `forEach` + `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<String, List<FamilyMember>> accumulator = new HashMap<>();
source.forEach(f -> accumulator.computeIfAbsent(f.getHouse(),
                  k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(new FamilyMember(f.getFamilyMember())));
```

Then take each entry from the `accumulator` and map it to a `House` object:

```
List<House> result = new ArrayList<>();
accumulator.forEach((house, familyMembers) -> result.add(new House(house, familyMembers)));
```